# Custom functionality: Editing Read Only Kendo UI Grid cell when it has dirty cell class applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo UI Grid. If the field has some value in it then it should appear as read only (not editable) otherwise it will be an editable cell.
Now, I have implemented the below given solution.

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/NX96g/175/][1]
```

It’s working fine. If the field has not a value or 'blank/Empty/Null' then that cell is editable.
But problem is if user enters some value in Empty/blank/Null cell, the cell becomes read only instantly and user not able to edit it.
How to let the user edit cell when it has dirty cell class applied ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is really an answer but...

Your DataSource has autoSync: true.  If you do *not* set it to true, then kendo will add a "k-dirty-cell" class to the cell/td which is persisted and used to append the k-dirty span that adds the red marker.

```
http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/uvaGI
```

This shows what you want working with autoSync: false and an extra check for the "k-dirty-cell" class:

```
if (!isEditable(fieldName, e.model) && !e.container.hasClass("k-dirty-cell")) {
```

When autoSync is true, the "k-dirty-cell" class is not used and then there is nothing to look for as if the changes are always saved immediately, then technically the cell is never dirty.

If you must have autoSync: true...I haven't been able to figure anything out yet.  I've played with adding a check on model.dirty but with autoSync on the model isn't dirty the second time in the editor as the autoSync saves the change immediately.

It is possible that you could use a variation of the technique here:

```
http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/preserve-the-dirty-indicator-in-incell-editing-and-client-operations
```

to keep track of the dirty cells manually in the model and integrate that check into your isEditable().

But, I would probably just turn off autoSync if you don't really need it.